# What does the first element of dummy_argv mean for perl_parse?

Tags: c, perl

Quoted from [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/prog3/ch21_04.htm):

```
static PerlInterpreter *my_perl;

main (int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
   STRLEN n_a;
   char *dummy_argv[] = { "", "-e", "0" };

   my_perl = perl_alloc();
   perl_construct( my_perl );

   perl_parse(my_perl, NULL, 3, dummy_argv, NULL);
   perl_run(my_perl);

   /** Treat $a as an integer **/
   eval_pv("$a = 3; $a **= 2", TRUE);
   printf("a = %d\n", SvIV(get_sv("a", FALSE)));

   /** Treat $a as a float **/
   eval_pv("$a = 3.14; $a **= 2", TRUE);
   printf("a = %f\n", SvNV(get_sv("a", FALSE)));

   /** Treat $a as a string **/
   eval_pv("$a = 'relreP kcaH rehtonA tsuJ'; $a = reverse($a);", TRUE);
   printf("a = %s\n", SvPV(get_sv("a", FALSE), n_a));

   perl_destruct(my_perl);
   perl_free(my_perl);
```

What does the first element of dummy_argv(here `""`) mean for perl_parse?

I tried to modify it to whatever I want and nothing changes..

Comment: You shouldn't link to pirated copies of O'Reilly books. .ua one is pirated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, `argv[0]` is the name of the program being executed.  In most cases, an embedded Perl interpreter doesn't really care what you put there, which is why you don't notice anything when you change it.

Remember that Perl is primarily a stand-alone interpreter; embedding it into other programs is a secondary use.  Perl's `main()` function just passes the same `argc` and `argv` that it received to  `perl_parse`, because that's what simplest.  When you call `perl_parse` in your program, you have to supply something for `argv[0]`, but I think the only thing it's used for is setting [`$^X`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24EXECUTABLE_NAME), which isn't used by most Perl code.

Comment: This is my real question: why does `perl_parse` require that first element if it's never used?

Comment: Seems wrong, I just tried to fetch it `gv = gv_fetchpv("^X", 0, SVt_PV);`, but only fetched a null pointer.

Comment: @new_perl, try fetching `"\030"` (an actual Ctrl-X) instead of `"^X"`.  You're operating below the level that transforms the special variable names.

Comment: I just tried, the assumption is wrong, $^X returns the binary file name no matter what the first element of `dummy_argv` is.

Comment: @new_perl, `argv[0]` is only one of the possible sources of `$^X`.  The actual mechanism by which Perl determines the value is platform-dependent; see `S_set_caret_X` in `perl.c`.  I guess your platform uses one of the other methods.  However, the `perl_parse` API is the same on all platforms, so you still need to supply some value, even if your platform isn't using it.